# Masked TextBox how to not show underlines in text box and allow user to enter 3 digits

Tags: c#, winforms, maskedtextbox

I am having some troubles with a masked textbox.

How can I hide those underlines which are shown in the textbox by default?!

Also I want the user be able to enter up to 3 digits (he/she can enter atleast 1 and maximum 3 digits). how to set that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set empty space(leave one space) in **Promptchar**  property of masked textbox.
and second answer you already get. or **you can put validation on Leave event for that.**